# How to have the sed output side by side?

Tags: bash, sed, layout

I want to have standard output for KEGG pathways of a gene placed side by side no matter how many lines of the KEGG pathways it has. For example, a gene TT123456 is involves in several pathways:

```
Valine, leucine and isoleucine degradation
Histidine metabolism
Ascorbate and aldarate metabolism
Lysine degradation
Glycerolipid metabolism
```

By using the sed command

```
sed '$!N;s/\n/\t/'
```

I able to have two lines joined side by side

```
Valine, leucine and isoleucine degradation  Histidine metabolism
Ascorbate and aldarate metabolism   Lysine degradation
Glycerolipid metabolism
```

But, I would like to have the output as

```
Valine, leucine and isoleucine degradation  Histidine metabolism    Ascorbate and aldarate metabolism   Lysine degradation  Glycerolipid metabolism
```

I have been searching around, but, I failed to find a good solution.

Could the community please shares your expertise with me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'ORS="\t"' file
```

```
$ awk 'ORS="\t"' file
Valine, leucine and isoleucine degradation      Histidine metabolism    Ascorbate and aldarate metabolism       Lysine degradation      Glycerolipid metabolism
```

If you wish to use `sed` then:

```
$ sed ':a;N;s/\n/\t/;ba' file
Valine, leucine and isoleucine degradation      Histidine metabolism    Ascorbate and aldarate metabolism       Lysine degradation      Glycerolipid metabolism
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I may, could you please explain ':a;N;s/\n/\t/;ba' more? Thanks. Your method works.

Comment: @KJLim `a` is label, `N` is to grab the next line with `\n`. We use normal substitution to replace newline with tabs. `:ba` is the critical part which allows you to loop back to label to continue this substitution until end of file.

Answer (score 4):

This is really what [`paste(1)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/paste.html) is for:

```
$ paste -s "$file"
Valine, leucine and isoleucine degradation  Histidine metabolism    Ascorbate and aldarate metabolism   Lysine degradation  Glycerolipid metabolism
```

Here's what the manpage says the `-s` flag should do:

> Concatenate all of the lines of each separate input file in command
>   line order. The `<newline>` of every line except the last line in each
>   input file shall be replaced with the `<tab>`, unless otherwise
>   specified by the -d option.

You can also process standard input by using a `-` instead of the filename.

```
somecommand | paste -s -
```

What's the difference between `tr '\n' '\t'` and `paste -s` (with an implied tab delimiter)? The former will strip even the trailing newline, but `paste` will leave the final newline intact. Also, `paste` can handle both standard input and files, but `tr` can *only* handle standard input.

Comment: +1 because this does not produce an extraneous tab at the end of the output. (Since the shell lets you trivially redirect stdin to a file, I don't really see the value-added of "paste can handle both standard input and files".)

Comment: @rici it's useful if you don't want to consume standard input, such as in a read loop or when piping a command to ssh.

Comment: @kojiro: `tr <file` doesn't "consume standard input". So what's the problem? Specific example, please.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `tr`:

```
tr '\n' '\t' < inputfile
```

For your input, it'd produce:

```
Valine, leucine and isoleucine degradation      Histidine metabolism    Ascorbate and aldarate metabolism       Lysine degradation      Glycerolipid metabolism
```

Using sed:

```
sed '$!{:a;N;s/\n/\t/;ta}' inputfile
```

Comment: Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22301883/418413) to differentiate `tr '\n' '\t'` and `paste -s`.

Comment: @kojiro I understand the difference between `tr` and `paste`.  Your note seems to indicate that there is something wrong with it.  If so, please indicate and feel free to downvote.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `tr`, but I felt making the distinction was important. I originally described the difference in my comment, but then decided it would be better to put it in my answer.

Comment: @kojiro So performing a _comparative analysis_ of different answers is your hobby?

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't pay as well as you might think.

Comment: @devnull Thanks. Your method works. Could you please explain '$!{:a;N;s/\n/\t/;ta}' more? Thanks.

Comment: @KJLim Unless it's the last line in the file, it joins the next line with the pattern space, replaces the newline with the tab character and loops again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use paste in serial mode:

```
paste -s file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xargs` like this:

```
$ xargs -n15 <file
Valine, leucine and isoleucine degradation Histidine metabolism Ascorbate and aldarate metabolism Lysine degradation Glycerolipid metabolism
```

Note `15` is the number of words in your file. You could write a bigger number like `xargs -n50 < file` to make sure everything printed in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Also `printf '%s ' $(< file)` or `printf '%s ' $(cat file)` if your shell doesn't have `$(< ...)`.